# How to add an image using create.image to a TopLevel?

Tags: python

I am trying to add an image to `TopLevel` using `create_image`. And I have an error: `AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'create_image'`.

Can you help me solve this problem please?

```
koniec=Toplevel()
koniec.minsize(width=200, height=250)
koniec.title("Víťaz!")
img=tkinter.PhotoImage(file='obrazok.gif')
koniec.create_image(100,100,image=obr)
```

Comment: Where is `obr` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Toplevel` doesn't have a `create_image` method, but `Canvas` does. You could add a `Canvas` to the `Toplevel`, and add your image to that.

```
koniec=Toplevel()
koniec.minsize(width=200, height=250)
koniec.title("Vítaz!")
canvas = Canvas(koniec, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()
img=tkinter.PhotoImage(file='obrazok.gif')
canvas.create_image(100,100,image=img)
```

Additionally, it may be necessary to have `canvas.image = img`, to prevent the [PhotoImage garbage collection bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430648/tkinter-vanishing-photoimage-issue).