# Tkinter 2.7- image won't show up in the window with Tk.mainloop()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label
def start_up():
    app = Tk()
    app.title("Tower")
    app.geometry('600x900')
    photo = PhotoImage("Python.png")
    label = Label(app, image = photo)
    label.pack()
    app.mainloop()
start_up()
```

I'm currently struggling with tkinter 2.7. I cannot display the image I want, therefore please take a look at my code and help me fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I voted to close for a minute there but on second look I don't think your problem has the same cause as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430648/python-tkinter-2-7-issue-with-image.

Comment: You have to `pack()` the label _before_ you call `mainloop()`.

Comment: I applied the change but it's still a white screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
from Tkinter import
```

This is a syntax error. When using the `from` syntax, you need to list the names you want imported. (or an asterisk to import everything, but that's not good practice since it pollutes your namespace unnecessarily)

```
from Tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label
```

```
label = Label(app, image = photo)
app.mainloop()
label.pack()
```

You're supposed to `pack()` your widgets before you call mainloop. Change this to:

```
label = Label(app, image = photo)
label.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

```
photo = PhotoImage("Python.png")
```

You're supposed to use the `file` keyword argument if you want to pass a filename to PhotoImage. Additionally, PhotoImage doesn't know how to open pngs. Try a format such as gif or pgm.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="Python.gif")
```

Alternatively, install the third party library Pillow, and use its [ImageTk.PhotoImage](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/ImageTk.html) class, which supports a wide variety of image formats, including png.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
img = Image.open("python.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label = Label(app, image = photo)
```

End result:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Label
def start_up():
    app = Tk()
    app.title("Tower")
    app.geometry('600x900')
    photo = PhotoImage(file="Python.gif")
    label = Label(app, image = photo)
    label.pack()
    app.mainloop()
start_up()
```

Comment: **_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Python.gif": no such file or directory**          I converted the png to gif and ran the code but the error message showed up. I tried fixing it by dragging the gif into the same directory but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @jaxk The image has to be placed in the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Alternatively, use an absolute path like `r'C:\Users\whatever\Python.gif'`. Or make the path [relative to the python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing).