# Image on Tkinter button is not showing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know why the image not showing.
Is this a device problem or some update in the Tkinter library?

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
btn = Button(master=root,image=PhotoImage(file='Sample1.png'))
btn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Sample Image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is because there is no variable reference the image, so the image will be garbage collected.  Use a variable to store the image reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.

Python garbage-collects any local objects at the end of the scope, even when being used by a Tkinter widget. To prevent this, you need to assign the image to some variable:

```py
photoimage = PhotoImage(file='Sample1.png')
btn = Button(master=root,image=photoimage)
```

Related: [Tkinter vanishing PhotoImage issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430648/tkinter-vanishing-photoimage-issue)