# GUI in a class with python + tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas

I have a problem putting a GUI in a class. Loading an image from a file, resize and display it on a canvas works as long the complete code runs in main().
In the code below I do the same steps in a class. The image is shown, but entering the mainloop() the canvas is cleared.

Many thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

class Gui():
    
    def __init__(self, window):       
        File = "/home/pi/Rainer/Graphic/Bahn01.png"
        img = self.load_image(File, 0.5)
       
        canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg='white')
        canvas.place(x=10, y=10, width=300, height=400)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")
        window.update()

    def load_image(self, File, Zoom):
        img = Image.open(File)
        resized_image = img.resize((int(600 * Zoom), int(800 * Zoom)), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

def main():  
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("620x420+320+20")
        
    App = Gui(root)
    
    time.sleep(3)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is because the `img` variable in your `Gui` class is a local variable within the `__init__` method. When the method finishes executing, the ``img variable is no longer referenced and gets `garbage-collected`. This causes the image to disappear from the `canvas`.

To fix this, you need to store the image as an instance variable of the `Gui` class. You can do this by using the `self` keyword.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

class Gui():
    
    def __init__(self, window):       
        File = "/home/pi/Rainer/Graphic/Bahn01.png"
        self.img = self.load_image(File, 0.5)
       
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg='white')
        self.canvas.place(x=10, y=10, width=300, height=400)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.img, anchor="nw")
        window.update()

    def load_image(self, File, Zoom):
        img = Image.open(File)
        resized_image = img.resize((int(600 * Zoom), int(800 * Zoom)), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

def main():  
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("620x420+320+20")
        
    App = Gui(root)
    
    time.sleep(3)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268418/image-on-tkinter-button-is-not-showing) for more help.

Comment: Replace this `time.sleep(3)` to `root.after(3000, main)`

Comment: @toyotaSupra that's in OP's Question.

Comment: The image is not cleared.